# Use powershell to start Active Directory Lightweight Directory Service

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-10, adlds

**Windows10 PRO & PowerShell v5.1**

I used `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeatures` cmdlet to enable the Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services.

When I try to use `Set-ADDomain`, it doesn't work, because *Active Directory Web Services* aren't running. I know I could use the ADLDS Setup Wizard to start this service. Does any cmdlet can achieve that ？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have enabled the windows feature Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services then no AD LDS instance has been added yet. You can add an AD LDS instance by running `%systemroot%\ADAM\adaminstall`, which is possible to run in silent mode as well if you need to script it.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816778(v=ws.10).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816774(v=ws.10).aspx for more information on how to add an AD LDS instance.

The command `Set-ADDomain` that you mention is to be used with an AD DS domain, which is not the same thing as AD LDS.

Answer (score 1):

```
sc [\\dc.contoso] start adws
```

In an elevated command prompt can do the trick.

```
Get-Service -Name adws [-ComputerName dc.contoso] | Start-Service
```

Is the Powershell pendant.

**In short**:

No, there isn't *"the special cmdlet to start ADWS"*, but it's easy to use PowerShell (or cmd) to start that service.